# How to programmatically confirm Gmail autoforwarding verification?

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-imap

To manually do this, the user will click the verification link in the email sent by Gmail. I wonder how to easily automate this? Does Google provides an API to do this? And without needing to ask the user's permission first.

I know that this is possible since I tried some apps that automatically confirms Gmail autoforwarding verification after Gmail sent the verification email to the forwarding address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically parse the verification link from the email and perform a GET request to that URL.

Note: You don't need to be logged in to Google when visiting that link.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract out the confirm link from the email. However, there is a bit of a gotcha here. The link in the email uses the domain:

```
https://mail-settings.google.com/mail/......
```

When the user clicks that email, the user is redirected to:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/.....
```

So, to confirm the forwarding request, you simply need to replace the `mail-settings.google.com` domain with `mail.google.com`, and then do a POST with an empty body to the resulting URL.

Also, a regex you can use to parse the URL out of the text version of the email is as follows:

```
confirm the request:\s*(https:\S+)
```